# "Method proposed" vs "proposed method"

Tags: grammar

Should we write "Method proposed" or "Proposed method" for the title of a section in an article?

Comment: I'd say that "proposed method" would sound more normal. However, "method proposed" has [front-loading](http://www.w3.org/WAI/wcag-curric/sam110-0.htm) benefits.

Comment: In my view this falls into the Chef's Choice category: if you're the chef, you get to choose.

Answer (score 4):

Both works. But IIRC the sentence that eventually comes out of them are quite different

Suppose that Captain Canada proposed a method of alien rump-kicking to the Canadian Department of Hockey Militarization (they do have that, right?) using hockey sticks, and you want to report on that

"(A) Method proposed by Captain Canada makes use of hockey sticks to kick alien rumps" < this is usually the kind I see as article titles

"The proposed method of kicking alien rumps by Captain Canada makes use of hockey sticks to kick alien rumps" < I can't imagine using "proposed method" phrase without using this structure

If I have to say, "method proposed" is better, mainly because it's much shorter and is indeed quite straight to the point